# mysql crashing with assertion failures and recovery

Tags: mysql

I'm having my mysql server crashing the last 3-4 days. The crash log TODAY shows the following:

```
2013-09-20 09:20:55 1244  InnoDB: Assertion failure in thread 4676 in file btr0cur.cc line 4766
InnoDB: Failing assertion: space_id == page_get_space_id(page)
InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to http://bugs.mysql.com.
InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
InnoDB: Thread 3792 stopped in file ut0ut.cc line 81
InnoDB: Thread 4088 stopped in file os0sync.cc line 475
InnoDB: Thread 4992 stopped in file os0sync.cc line 783
InnoDB: Thread 2896 stopped in file ut0ut.cc line 81
InnoDB: Thread 3724 stopped in file ut0lst.h line 93
InnoDB: Thread 4580 stopped in file ut0lst.h line 93
InnoDB: Thread 3164 stopped in file os0sync.cc line 475
InnoDB: Thread 3364 stopped in file os0sync.cc line 475
InnoDB: Thread 444 stopped in file os0sync.cc line 475
InnoDB: Thread 3964 stopped in file ut0lst.h line 93
InnoDB: Thread 4048 stopped in file ha_innodb.cc line 4007
InnoDB: Thread 3780 stopped in file ha_innodb.cc line 4007
InnoDB: Thread 3480 stopped in file ha_innodb.cc line 4007
InnoDB: Thread 4568 stopped in file ha_innodb.cc line 4007
InnoDB: Thread 4060 stopped in file ha_innodb.cc line 4007
InnoDB: Thread 1380 stopped in file ha_innodb.cc line 2316
2013-09-20 10:34:19 3700 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2013-09-20 10:34:19 3700 [Warning] option 'innodb-autoextend-increment': unsigned value 67108864 adjusted to 1000
2013-09-20 10:34:19 12dc InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2013-09-20 10:34:19 3700 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2013-09-20 10:34:19 3700 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2013-09-20 10:34:19 3700 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2013-09-20 10:34:19 3700 [Note] InnoDB: CPU does not support crc32 instructions
2013-09-20 10:34:19 3700 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 2.0G
2013-09-20 10:34:19 3700 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2013-09-20 10:34:19 3700 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2013-09-20 10:34:20 3700 [Note] InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 4361137083
2013-09-20 10:34:20 3700 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2013-09-20 10:34:20 3700 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2013-09-20 10:34:20 3700 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
2013-09-20 10:34:20 3700 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages 
2013-09-20 10:34:20 3700 [Note] InnoDB: from the doublewrite buffer...
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 4361156792
2013-09-20 10:34:21 3700 [Note] InnoDB: Starting an apply batch of log records to the database...
InnoDB: Progress in percent: 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 
InnoDB: Apply batch completed
2013-09-20 10:34:21 3700 [Warning] Invalid (old?) table or database name '#sql-564_1361f'
2013-09-20 10:34:21 3700 [Warning] Invalid (old?) table or database name '#sql-c28_63'
2013-09-20 10:34:21 3700 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2013-09-20 10:34:21 3700 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2013-09-20 10:34:22 3700 [Note] InnoDB: 1.2.10 started; log sequence number 4361156792
2013-09-20 10:34:22 3700 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2013-09-20 10:34:22 3700 [Note] IPv6 is available.
2013-09-20 10:34:22 3700 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
2013-09-20 10:34:22 3700 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2013-09-20 10:34:22 3700 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2013-09-20 10:34:22 3700 [Note] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.6.10-log'  socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

while on the previous days i have had more crashes which look like this:

```
Version: '5.6.10-log'  socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
2013-09-18 09:05:47 1096 [Warning] Host name 'unassigned.psychz.net' could not be resolved: No such host is known. 
InnoDB: Database page corruption on disk or a failed
InnoDB: file read of page 80044.
InnoDB: You may have to recover from a backup.
2013-09-18 10:03:57 7dc InnoDB: Page dump in ascii and hex (16384 bytes):
 len 16384; hex 00000000000000000...
InnoDB: End of page dump
2013-09-18 10:03:57 7dc InnoDB: uncompressed page, stored checksum in field1 0, calculated checksums for field1: crc32 71317206, innodb 2798848053, none 3735928559, stored checksum in field2 4275117012, calculated checksums for field2: crc32 71317206, innodb 1371122432, none 3735928559, page LSN 0 0, low 4 bytes of LSN at page end 1766966405, page number (if stored to page already) 0, space id (if created with >= MySQL-4.1.1 and stored already) 0
InnoDB: Page may be a freshly allocated page
InnoDB: Database page corruption on disk or a failed
InnoDB: file read of page 80044.
InnoDB: You may have to recover from a backup.
InnoDB: It is also possible that your operating
InnoDB: system has corrupted its own file cache
InnoDB: and rebooting your computer removes the
InnoDB: error.
InnoDB: If the corrupt page is an index page
InnoDB: you can also try to fix the corruption
InnoDB: by dumping, dropping, and reimporting
InnoDB: the corrupt table. You can use CHECK
InnoDB: TABLE to scan your table for corruption.
InnoDB: See also http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
InnoDB: Database page corruption on disk or a failed
InnoDB: file read of page 80044.
InnoDB: You may have to recover from a backup.
2013-09-18 10:03:57 7dc InnoDB: Page dump in ascii and hex (16384 bytes):
 len 16384; hex 000
InnoDB: End of page dump
2013-09-18 10:03:58 7dc InnoDB: uncompressed page, stored checksum in field1 0, calculated checksums for field1: crc32 71317206, innodb 2798848053, none 3735928559, stored checksum in field2 4275117012, calculated checksums for field2: crc32 71317206, innodb 1371122432, none 3735928559, page LSN 0 0, low 4 bytes of LSN at page end 1766966405, page number (if stored to page already) 0, space id (if created with >= MySQL-4.1.1 and stored already) 0
InnoDB: Page may be a freshly allocated page
InnoDB: Database page corruption on disk or a failed
InnoDB: file read of page 80044.
InnoDB: You may have to recover from a backup.
InnoDB: It is also possible that your operating
InnoDB: system has corrupted its own file cache
InnoDB: and rebooting your computer removes the
InnoDB: error.
InnoDB: If the corrupt page is an index page
InnoDB: you can also try to fix the corruption
InnoDB: by dumping, dropping, and reimporting
InnoDB: the corrupt table. You can use CHECK
InnoDB: TABLE to scan your table for corruption.
InnoDB: See also http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
InnoDB: Ending processing because of a corrupt database page.
2013-09-18 10:03:58 7dc  InnoDB: Assertion failure in thread 2012 in file buf0buf.cc line 4057
InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to http://bugs.mysql.com.
InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
InnoDB: Thread 1528 stopped in file os0sync.cc line 475
InnoDB: Thread 1532 stopped in file os0sync.cc line 783
InnoDB: Thread 1548 stopped in file ut0ut.cc line 81
InnoDB: Thread 1540 stopped in file ut0ut.cc line 81
InnoDB: Thread 1556 stopped in file os0sync.cc line 475
InnoDB: Thread 1536 stopped in file os0sync.cc line 475
InnoDB: Thread 1560 stopped in file os0sync.cc line 475
InnoDB: Thread 2380 stopped in file ut0lst.h line 93
InnoDB: Thread 544 stopped in file ut0lst.h line 93
InnoDB: Thread 2996 stopped in file ut0lst.h line 93
InnoDB: Thread 632 stopped in file ut0lst.h line 93
InnoDB: Thread 2884 stopped in file ha_innodb.cc line 4007
InnoDB: Thread 2248 stopped in file ha_innodb.cc line 4007
2013-09-18 10:19:39 1380 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2013-09-18 10:19:39 1380 [Warning] option 'innodb-autoextend-increment': unsigned value 67108864 adjusted to 1000
2013-09-18 10:19:39 b4c InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2013-09-18 10:19:39 1380 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2013-09-18 10:19:39 1380 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2013-09-18 10:19:39 1380 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2013-09-18 10:19:39 1380 [Note] InnoDB: CPU does not support crc32 instructions
2013-09-18 10:19:39 1380 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 2.0G
2013-09-18 10:19:39 1380 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2013-09-18 10:19:40 1380 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2013-09-18 10:19:40 1380 [Note] InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 1770390822
2013-09-18 10:19:40 1380 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2013-09-18 10:19:40 1380 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2013-09-18 10:19:40 1380 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
2013-09-18 10:19:40 1380 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages 
2013-09-18 10:19:40 1380 [Note] InnoDB: from the doublewrite buffer...
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 1770395124
2013-09-18 10:19:41 1380 [Note] InnoDB: Starting an apply batch of log records to the database...
InnoDB: Progress in percent: 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 
InnoDB: Apply batch completed
2013-09-18 10:19:42 1380 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2013-09-18 10:19:42 1380 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2013-09-18 10:19:42 1380 [Note] InnoDB: 1.2.10 started; log sequence number 1770395124
2013-09-18 10:19:42 1380 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2013-09-18 10:19:42 1380 [Note] IPv6 is available.
2013-09-18 10:19:42 1380 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
2013-09-18 10:19:42 1380 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2013-09-18 10:19:43 1380 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2013-09-18 10:19:43 1380 [Note] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.6.10-log'  socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

i belive some of the errors were due to a corrupted table which i truncated.

I was wondering if there are some more reasons for the assertion failures and what can I do to avoid such things.

Also those hostnames "unassigned.psychz.net" which are unresolved, why exactly do they appear in the log? what does it mean ? only 1 particular IP can connect to the mysql server ( firewall ) so i don't understand why that message is there.

Thank you in advance any input.

Answer (score -1):

I am looking into mysql connection attempts from unassigned.psychz.net

It is beginning to look as if these are hacking attempts

Comment: We had a similar situation. Any hints on what you did afterwards?